# Connecting nodes in an array

Tags: java, arrays, graph, tree, nodes

What is the best way to approach the following issue?

I am given a 2d array of nodes that looks like this

```
1083    1676
1083    1084
1084    1085
1085    1086
```

each line contains two nodes that are connected to each other. I need to create a tree (binary tree is preferred) where all the nodes are connected to each other.

What type of tree algorithm in java should be used? Is there a type of graph that can be used to plot two points and connect them to other points?

Comment: Your request is unclear. A tree is a very specific type of graph; how exactly is it supposed to relate to your collection of node pairs?

Comment: `I need to create a tree [...] where all the nodes are connected to each other.` This is not a tree, as it would create cycles. Or do you want to create a tree from the given array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your input completely describes the layout of the tree, not complicated logic is needed.

```
for each line
  split line into two values.
  if a node exists for the value1
    p = that node
  else
    p = new Node(value1)
  if a node exists for the value2
    c = that node
  else
    c = new Node(value2)
  set c as child to parent
```